# Running Julia and Python on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, julia

I have been using Visual Studio Code to work with `Julia` files over the last few months. Previously, I was working with `Python` in the Spyder IDE, where I had downloaded the Anaconda distribution to install Python and various packages in my PC and then installed Jupyter notebooks and the Spyder IDE. I would like to use Visual Studio for both `Python` and `Julia`. I have installed the Python Extension on VS Code, by Microsoft, and after I open a file, I am prompted to select between two Python Interpreters

1. Python 3.9.5 ~\julia\conda\3\python.exe
2. Python 3.8.10 ('base') ~\anaconda3\python.exe

However, my program does not seem to work with either of these interpreters. The same program however, works on Spyder. How do I get Python to work on VS Code while I have previously used it for Julia?

Comment: Did you reload vscode after installing the python extension?

Comment: You should give more details. I'm using VSCode for both languages without any problem. have you installed the Python extension? How did you try to run a `.py` file in VSCode?

Comment: Have you tried to install python from the official website?

Comment: @RohithNambiar, yes. That doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Shayan, as I mentioned in the post, I have installed the Python extension on VS Code. After I installed it, I opened VS Code again, opened the `.py` file from File -> Open, and then tried it with both interpreters as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT, no I have not. I have the anaconda distribution. Do I require installation only from the official website to run it on VS Code?

Comment: @newtothis I said *"How did you try to run a `.py` file in VSCode?"*

Comment: @newtothis Could you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: I was trying to run the file using the triangle play button at the top right. However, it seems to work (after an initial error) if I use `Shift` + `Enter` after selecting whichever code block I want executed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is `python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Administrator\ipython': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`?

If it is, you need to open a folder then create a file in it instead of just open a file directly.